# SQL Syntax on Using Row_Number for price sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I kept my SQL Syntax in this sqlfiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80e00/8

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT left(modelnumber,4) as ModelNumber,
  packetsize,
  price,
  row_number() over ( partition BY left(modelnumber,4),packetsize,price ORDER BY price ASC ) AS rownumber
  FROM test
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

I am trying to sort the price of modelnumbers in ascending order.

I am not sure, why my syntax is not returning the output as expected.

My goal is to pick the lowest price for Left(ModelNumber,4). In order to do so. I need a WHERE Condition. Such as `select * from cte where rownumber = 1 order by price asc`. But in the present output, we get all rownumbers = 1

Expected Output

```
MODELNUMBER     PACKETSIZE      PRICE    ROWNUMBER
1000              1.1           10.5      1
1000              1.1           11.5      2
1000              1.1           13        3
1000              1.1           15        4
1000              2.1           10.5      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition clause of ROW_NUMBER indicates when you want to reset the numbering to 1.

By partitioning by ModelNumber,Packetsize *and* Price you're picking a nearly distinct values to restart the numbering.

All you really need to do is drop the "price" from partition.

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT left(modelnumber,4) as ModelNumber,
  packetsize,
  price,
  row_number() over ( partition BY left(modelnumber,4),packetsize ORDER BY price ASC ) AS rownumber
  FROM test
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80e00/29)

Comment: Thank you conrad. My syntax mistakes. It works well . Thank you